# Mocha Chai unexpected assertion Error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have a mocha/chai assertion giving me an error, despite the values being the same

[image]

Test code is here:

```
describe("Util.SplitNumAndOper Tests", function(){
    it('should have "6+4+3" return [6,"+",4,"+",3]', function(){
        let a = util.splitNumAndOper("6+4+3");
        assert.equal(a,[6,'+',4,'+',3]);
    })
})
```

What's going on here?

Comment: I assume it has something to do with strict equals (same location in memory) vs a regular equal, but I could not find a deep-equals in chais assertion library.

Comment: You should use deepEqual

Comment: okay that worked `assert.deepEqual(a,[6,'+',4,'+',3]);`

Comment: With chai, you can use expect(array).eql([...]) for comparing two arrays by values

Answer (score 0):

[.equal(actual, expected, [message])](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_equal) method asserts non-strict equality (`==`) of actual and expected

[.deepEqual(actual, expected, [message])](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_deepequal) asserts that actual is deeply equal to expected

In your case, `actual` and `expected` value are all `Array`, they refer to different arrays. They have different pointers in memory. So `.equal` will fail.

```js
import { assert } from "chai";

describe("Util.SplitNumAndOper Tests", function(){
  it('should have "6+4+3" return [6,"+",4,"+",3]', function(){
    const  a = [6,'+',4,'+',3];
    assert.equal(a,[6,'+',4,'+',3]);
  })
})
```

unit test result:

```
  Util.SplitNumAndOper Tests
    ✓ should have "6+4+3" return [6,"+",4,"+",3]


  1 passing (75ms)
```